# Manipulating elements using the display property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #myDIV {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: none;
        }

        #second {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try this now</button>
    <div id="myDIV">
        This is my DIV element.
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        This is my DIV2 element.
    </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function myFunction2() {
            document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

So i have this code that will make a div element appear on clicking on a button. However i want once i click on "second" button, i want the "`myDiv`" to disappear and "second" takes its place(the exact position) and vice versa.

Any help please?

Comment: You'd think it would be rather obvious to replace `"block"` with `"none"`  in the second function ?

Comment: @adeneo - indeed, but sometimes we just need a second set of eyes!

Comment: @adeneo they do not alternate in position

Comment: @adeneo maybe you'd think to check typo s answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

<script>
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is there anyway to make each div fade in and out?

Comment: here's a tutorial http://tech.pro/tutorial/725/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation